# How to extract values from intersection of different size buffers with raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, buffer, gme, extract-by-mask

I have a polygon shape with buffers. However, the buffers are of different size from 4m radius to 15m. In total I have 7 different buffers.

I have a landcover raster and I would like to extract values from that raster for each of my buffers. I would like to get either the proportion of each cover type within each buffer or the major cover type for each buffer.

I am using ArcGIS 10. I tried using GME and intersect polygon with raster and almost all my fields are treated as noData... Both my raster and my polygon files have the same coordinate system and projection.

I was about to use CON() for each landcover, then neighborhood and then extract values to point but there might be a faster way.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you convert your rasters to polygon, and then do the an intersect with the buffers.  This will give you the cells from the polygon.  This will give the option to do statistics on the intersected buffered areas.

Comment: Using arcMap or GME? Is it usually more efficient using polygon instead of raster?

Comment: Be mindful when converting raster to polygon that the resulting file won't always have the exact number of cells that the raster had. If two adjacent cells have the same value then they are converted to a single polygon. That is why you have to calculate by area rather than polygon count.

Answer (score 1):

[Tabulate Area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tabulate_Area/009z000000w2000000/) will work most efficiently if the buffers do not overlap.

If the buffers overlap then you can try the free ACCRU Tools [7.1.2 Overlap Area Sampling](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/?Page=3063#tools) after converting the landcover classes to binary using [2.2.3 Binary Class Conversions](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/?Page=3063#tools).